# history.back() with Android on Ionic

Tags: android, refresh, history, ionic-framework

How do I not refresh the page when calling history.back() on Android with Ionic? It works fine on iOS, but on Android it's reloading the page. I'm on cordova 3.5.

Comment: [Check this out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6464821/how-to-prevent-activity-to-reload-on-back-action)

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for the `$ionicNavBarDelgate.back()` method. This uses the `ui.router` state to navigate back in the history without reloading the page.

See: [$ionicNavBarDelegate](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicNavBarDelegate/)

**HTML**

```
<button type="button" class="button button-clear" ng-click="goBack()">Back</button>
```

**Javascript Controller**

```
angular.module('App').controller('PageCtrl', function ($scope, $ionicNavBarDelegate) {
  $scope.goBack = function () {
    $ionicNavBarDelegate.back();
  };
});
```

Comment: $ionicNavBarDelegate.back(); is depricated. Use $ionicHistory.goBack(); instead

Comment: Thank you, @Nico!  I was looking everywhere for this!